# Constructing a table with multilevel headers using `rich.table`

Tags: python, printing, format

I want to construct a table that has multi-level headers. I have written the following code using `rich`. But this is not how I want it.

```py
from rich.console import Console, Group
from rich.columns import Columns
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich.table import Table, Column


table = Table(title="Nested")
table.add_column("A")
table.add_column("B")
st = Table()
st.add_column("C")
st.add_column("D")
tt = Table()
tt.add_column("E")
tt.add_column("F")
table.add_row(st, tt)
console = Console()
console.print(table)
```

It looks like

[image]

Here, C and D must be second level headers to A. This applies to E, F as well

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with padding and line/edge visibility this is what I've come up with.

Column A is updated while column B is the same as your example code for reference.
I've also tried varying the `show_lines` parameter in the column A inner table (show_lines=True on top, False on the bottom), which just toggles the visibility of the horizontal lines.

[image: console output of tables]

As far as I know this is the closest we can get to the table looking right without the characters being replaced at the line intersections, which would require new functionality in the rich library per [this github discussion](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/issues/2602):

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃A         ┃B               ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│C   ┃D    │┏━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓│
│━━━━╇━━━━━│┃ E    ┃ F     ┃│
│test│test2│┡━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━┩│
│────┼─────││ test │ test2 ││
│test│test2││ test │ test2 ││
│────┼─────││ test │ test2 ││
│test│test2│└──────┴───────┘│
└──────────┴────────────────┘
```

Per the dev: "This feature is called "colspan", which isn't currently supported. It might be in the future."

My example code:

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

table = Table(title="Nested", padding=(0, 0))
table.add_column("A")
table.add_column("B")

st = Table(
    padding=(0, 0),
    show_edge=False,
    show_lines=True,
)
st.add_column("C")
st.add_column("D")
for _ in range(3):
    st.add_row("test", "test2")

tt = Table()
tt.add_column("E")
tt.add_column("F")
for _ in range(3):
    tt.add_row("test", "test2")

table.add_row(st, tt)

console = Console()
console.print(table)
```

**Update/Note**: you can actually remove `padding=(0, 0)` on the inner table without affecting the grid lines.